# Remote connectivity issue with QSqlDatabase [ODBC]

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt5, qsqldatabase

I'm trying to make a connection to a remote `SQL` server :

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC3");
    db.setDatabaseName(QString("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=X.X.X.X;Database=/*DB*/;"));
    db.setUserName("sa");
    db.setPassword("/*password*/");

    if (!db.open()) {
        qDebug() << db.lastError().text();
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "connected";
    }
```

But after about 7 sec it gives me this log :

> [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Named Pipes Provider: Could
>   not open a connection to SQL Server [1326].  [Microsoft][SQL Server
>   Native Client 10.0]A network-related or instance-specific error has
>   occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not
>   found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL
>   Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information
>   see SQL Server Books Online. [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client
>   10.0]Login timeout expired QODBC3: Unable to connect

However server is up and running and the connectivity is ok and already tested with `UDL` file.

Note: the local connection works well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use these settings, having the user and pass in the dbname, please:

```
QString connectString = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};"; // Driver can also be {SQL Server Native Client 11.0}
connectString.append("Server=SERVERHOSTNAME\\SQLINSTANCENAME;");   // Hostname,SQL-Server Instance
connectString.append("Database=SQLDBSCHEMA;");  // Schema
connectString.append("Uid=SQLUSER;");           // User
connectString.append("Pwd=SQLPASS;");           // Pass
db.setDatabaseName(connectString);
if(db.open())
{
    ui->statusBar->showMessage("Connected");
}else{
    ui->statusBar->showMessage("Not Connected");
}
```

or not using a full DSN

```
QString connectString = "Driver={SQL Server};"; // Driver is now {SQL Server}
connectString.append("Server=10.1.1.15,5171;"); // IP,Port
connectString.append("Database=SQLDBSCHEMA;");  // Schema
connectString.append("Uid=SQLUSER;");           // User
connectString.append("Pwd=SQLPASS;");           // Pass
db.setDatabaseName(connectString);
if(db.open())
{
    ui->statusBar->showMessage("Connected");
}else{
    ui->statusBar->showMessage("Not Connected");
}
```

Important for having a ip/port based connection is to have this type of connection enabled in the server configuration. Default one **cannot** connect using ip/port directly.

from https://wiki.qt.io/ODBC